# deleting row from JTable and database

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to delete Selected row data from Jtable  and database.

My Code :

```
 try {

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        model.removeRow(jTable1.getSelectedRow());

        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\management.db");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        int id = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
        Object number =  jTable1.getValueAt(id-1,0);
        String sql = "delete  from emp_details where id ="+number;
        int res = st.executeUpdate(sql);
        if(res == 1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Deleted", "Emp Details", WIDTH);
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Empsearch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Empsearch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

When I run the program get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2
```

Answer (score 0):

When removeRow() gets called, any row selection is undone, so the subsequent call to getSelectedRow() returns -1, thus setting id to -1. This results in getValueAt having id-1 (i.e. -2) as its first parameter, which of course is an invalid row index, hence the exception.
Perhaps try executing the SQL update and then deleting the table row?